# SharePoint 2010 Application becomes unresponsive between early hours of the morning

Tags: 2010, site

One of our SharePoint 2010 Applications/Website went down between 00:00am and 05:00am. I have checked the logs and no errors have been recorded that is noticeably different. Are there any other reasons why this site would go down temporarily? Not sure what else to provide, if you can think of any information that would be helpful to help diagnose this issue please let me know.

Any help would be very useful.

Thanks.

GH

Comment: what you mean by down, Web application or custom sites etc?

Comment: It is a Web Application and when users have tried to visit the site between the times above, the Web Application did not render. This is a stand alone Web Application and is not part of a site collection. (Relatively new to SP myself) @WaqasSarwarMVP

Comment: is it go down complete for 5 hours or just for few min?

Comment: It was reported a few times to be down for a few hours each time however this time it was reported that it was down for roughly 5 hours. I thought it maybe something to do with our nightly backups but i couldn't see why that would make the site inaccessible.  @WaqasSarwarMVP

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The IIS Application Pool recycles every night and needs to be warmed up again. You can check in IIS what time it is configured to recycle.

If you do not have warm-up in place then the first user will experience SharePoint as unresponsive on the first request.

Comment: I have checked this and our nightly/daily App Pool recycle is at 01:45am every morning. Could this potentially be the issue?

Comment: Yes, indeed! Try setting up a scheduled script that warms it up again. See this script https://github.com/spjeff/spbestwarmup